# LINQ to Entities returns null but generated SQL works fine

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following query which after executing sets the arts variable to null.

In SQL Server Profiler I can see the query is well formed, is being executed and is returning rows (there's only one thing to notice: the query includes all columns of all the tables involved).

Why the results collection is set to null even when the SQL query is working?
And why does the SQL query include all the columns and not only the ones specified in the anonymous type?

Thanks a lot.

Dial.

```
var arts = from rp in ent.ReportesDePrecios
           join arp in ent.ArtículosDeReporteDePrecios on rp.Id equals arp.ReporteDePreciosId
           //join crp in ent.CategoríasDeReporteDePrecios on rp.Id equals crp.ReporteDePreciosId
           join a in ent.Artículos on arp.ArtículoId equals a.Id
           where a.CategoríaId != null
           join p in ent.Precios on new { Precio = a.Id, rp.ListaDePreciosId } equals new { Precio = p.ArtículoId, p.ListaDePreciosId }
           where p.Activo == true
           select new 
                  { 
                      CategoríaId = a.CategoríaId.Value, 
                      a.FabricanteId, 
                      ArtículoId = a.Id, 
                      a.Código,  
                      Precio = p.Valor 
                  };
```

Comment: First things first: Are you calling FirstOrDefault () ? if so ... then we can discuss further, otherwise if you return a collection (you call ToList()) you could NEVER have a null reference, in the worst case you will have an empty collection. So what's your case ?

Comment: Why are there so many joins? Typically with a well designed EF context, you should be using association instead of join.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, one table was empty. That was one of the problems. Thanks a lot.